# Matching on an AD group using XSL

Tags: xslt

Ok, I pretty much know nothing about XSL. I want to loop through the users memberof and do something and if no match then do something else. I have the following which sort of works for our fax system. When a user in an AD group, they get delegated rights in the system. This is version 1.0.

I hope I added the code correctly

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:rf="urn:rightfax-sync-schema"
xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema"
exclude-result-prefixes="rf"
version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<!-- Copy all nodes and attributes. -->
<xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

  <!-- "userID" is a required attribute -->
  <xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='sAMAccountName']">
    <attr name="UserID">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </attr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='objectSid']">
    <attr name="AssociatedNTAccountSID">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </attr>
    <attr name="RequiresNTAuth">
      <value>True</value>
    </attr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='company']">
    <attr name="ToCompany">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </attr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='facsimileTelephoneNumber']">
    <!-- Commented out because AD users have the same fax number assigned to multiple users <attr name="RouteCode">
      <value>
         Get the last 4 digits of fax number, ignoring various special characters that might
         be found in phone numbers.  If result is Not a Number then use default route code instead.
         <xsl:variable name="cleanNumber" select="translate(node(), ' .-,()', '')"/>
         <xsl:variable name="routecode" select="substring($cleanNumber, string-length($cleanNumber)-6, 7)"/>
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string(number($routecode))='NaN'">100</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$routecode"/></xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </value>
    </attr> -->
    <attr name="PersonalFaxNum">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </attr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='l']">
    <attr name="ToCityState">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </attr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='name']">
    <attr name="UserName">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </attr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber']">
    <attr name="GeneralFaxNum">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </attr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='otherTelephone']">
    <attr name="GeneralVoiceNum">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </attr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='telephoneNumber']">
    <attr name="PersonalVoiceNum">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </attr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='memberOf']">
    <attr name="GroupID">
        <xsl:for-each select='*'>
            <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
            <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
            <xsl:variable name="tmpVar" select="substring-after(node(), '=')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="groupName" select="translate(substring-before(substring-after(node(), '='), ','), $uppercase, $smallcase)"/>
             <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string($groupName)='OT_group1_delegates'"><value>9</value></xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="string($groupName)='OT_group2_delegates'"><value>11</value></xsl:when>

                <xsl:otherwise><value>1</value></xsl:otherwise>

             </xsl:choose>  
        </xsl:for-each>
    </attr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='legacyExchangeDN']">
  </xsl:template>



  <xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='msExchVoiceMailboxID']">
    <attr name="BigVoiceMailSubscriberID">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </attr>
  </xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='mail']">
    <attr name="EmailAddress">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </attr>
    <attr name="RouteInfo">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </attr>
    <!-- Commented out to force routing from default user<attr name="RouteType">
      <value>11</value> Exchange = 11
    </attr> -->
    <attr name="NotifyInfo">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </attr>
    <attr name="NotifyType">
      <!-- Exchange = 17, SMTP = 18 -->
      <value>18</value>
    </attr>
    <attr name="RouteFormat">
      <value>2</value> <!-- TIFF = 2 -->
    </attr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So when that runs if I remark out the otherwise line it works fine. If a user is in one of the OT groups they get the delegated rights. However if I unremark the otherwise line, it will add them and then remove them due to the <1>. Is there any way to say if the user wasnt in one of those AD groups, then do the otherwise? Kinda like once it matches 1 stop?

Ideally it would also only look for AD groups that start with OT_ since a user could have dozens of groups.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please post enough code (XML, XSLT and the expected output) that would allow us to reproduce the problem - see [mcve].

Comment: Basically if a user does not have an AD group that matches OT_* do the otherwise line?

Comment: The behavior of `xsl:choose` is well-documented. Your description does not match it, so there is something else at work here. The sooner you let us see it, the sooner we'll know what it is.

Comment: Well what happens is say a user has more than a small # of AD groups, it looks like the otherwise is applying the value <1>. Im guessing because even though it found a match, the next AD group does not match so it does the otherwise.

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything. Give us code that we can run for ourselves.

Comment: When I try and paste i the XSL it says its too long. How do I do that?

Comment: Did you not read the link in my first comment? It says:  "*Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem*"

Comment: I only added the code that causes the issue. The part I posted was the only section relevant to memberof. Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: The fact you are working with AD (which I assume is Active Directory?) is probably not relevant to question. XSLT transforms an XML document to another format (in your case, another XML document). So, it would help if you showed a sample of your XML document, and the output you expect in that case. Thank you!

Comment: I only mentioned AD so it would be understood what the memberof is for. I cannot find any xml files, only XSL files. I was just trying to see how I could change the small section of member of code I originally posted so that when it find the 1st memberof AD group match it stops. I did see some other examples where you do the [1] but I'm not a coder. Jut trying to make something work in a production system.